# MSMQ - Error while trying to Receive message

Tags: c#, msmq

I am new to MSMQ and working on the existing code.

Here is my code.

```
  bool queueReadStatus = true;
  while (queueReadStatus)
  {
      try
       {
          Message message = messageQueue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
          msgLst.Add(message);
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException exception)
        {
            var ex = exception;
            queueReadStatus = false;
         }
     }
```

I got the below exception. Can someone help me trying to understand what exactly is the issue ?

[image: Exception in Immediate window]

Comment: What you are showing there appears to be the message that was returned, not the exception that was thrown (if any).

Comment: Yes, but there are invalid operation execptions in that screenshot right?

Comment: Those stem from property evaluations, not what your code did or didn't do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MSMQ Invalid Operation Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875912/c-sharp-msmq-invalid-operation-exception)